# Show all dates between two dates in M language excel

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'm doing a date dimension based workbook on Excel and I'm stuck at creating a new table for showing all days between two dates that lie in my workbook's cells `B2:Bx` and `C2:Cx`. In the M-language editor I'm trying to create a new column for showing the days in format 1.1.2018. It could probably be done with functions like `=DAYS(YEAR(B2:Cx))` but I'm trying to figure out a way in PowerQuery. So I need `B` and `C` columns as a reference and all dates in between the first date in `B` and last date in `C`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a new column,input`= List.Transform({Number.From([FirstDate])..Number.From([LastDate])},Date.From)`,return a list contains all dates,then expand it.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly for my project! If I may ask do you have any idea on how to split a value of a cell between the dates on the same row? Like splitting a cell with value '30' between 1.1-1.2 would equal 1 for each day?

Comment: Do you want to divide the value by total days?Try this:`=[Value]/Number.From([LastDate]-[FirstDate])`,then expand it.

Comment: Oh thanks works like a charm. I'm not sure if Im going to use this but I couldnt find out how to refer to a month, like if were to calculate value for January, how can I get the first 30 days and multiply it by the daily value? Same goes for the other months.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot to describe your problem, including source data and expected results?

Comment: https://ibb.co/gpA6Nd https://ibb.co/hO848J Theres the excel first and date_list contains the dates for the months that are active for the category on that row. I need the workload per month calculated from the days on date_list. My problem is I dont know how to refer to the particular days I need from date_list.

Comment: The first picture is your source data right?Please simulate your expected result.

Comment: Yes it is the source. I think it should look something like this: https://ibb.co/cPC0Xd I would combine the total workload before it would look like this, probably in a query. If there were only 2 categories from Jan.18 - Mar.18 with 6 man-months of workload in both, the additional workbook should show only Jan and Feb with 6 man-months each.

Comment: Is there a way to do this but only return the months in the list?  So instead of 11/01/2019, 11/02/2019, 11/03/2019, etc. you would have 11/01/2019, 12/01/2019, 01/01/2020, etc.